# Как проверить наличие директории в корне проекта без абсолютной ссылки? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проект выглядит так:

```
project_name/logic/somefile.py
project_name/anotherfile.py
```

...
В **somefile.py** я пытаюсь реализовать логику проверки наличия директории: **/project_name/tmp/** и если ее там нет, то создавать эту директорию, чтобы скрипт продолжал работу. Хочу сделать это без указания полного пути.

Не придумал лучшего "костыля", как в **anotherfile.py** (т.к. он лежит там, где нужно) добавить переменную:

```
project_dir = os.getcwd()
```

и потом уже, импортируя эту переменную, работать с ней в somefile.py:

```
from anotherfile import project_dir

if not path.isdir(project_dir + '/tmp'):
        mkdir(project_dir + '/tmp')
```

Но видимо, я присваиваю в переменную вызов функции, а не значение, поэтому из **anotherfile.py** она возвращает путь: **.../project_name/**, а через **somefile.py** эта переменная возвращает **.../project_name/logic/** - такие мои догадки...

Подскажите, пож-та:

1. Где я ошибаюсь в project_dir = os.getcwd()?
2. Как лучше реализовать проверку и создание директории .../project_name/tmp/?

Comment: ```if not path.isdir(project_dir + '/tmp'):
        mkdir(project_dir + '/tmp')  ``` Исправьте, тут должно бить два "//"

Comment: ```from anotherfile import project_dir
if not path.isdir(project_dir + '//tmp'):
        mkdir(project_dir + '//tmp')  ``` так правильно

Comment: @ІванШнір `\\\` двойной обратный для виндовс, прямой одинарный работает для всех современных ос (включая виндовс)

Comment: @ІванШнір а зачем '//' ? Прост у меня с одним нормально формирует путь.

Comment: Ну как бы либо в начале ставиш r либо // потому что пайтон может не понять

Comment: @ІванШнір путаешь с обратным;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай проект пакетом - добавь пустой `__init__.py`. Тогда

```
import project_name
```

`project_name.__file__` будет `**/project_name/__init__.py` и вот:

```
import os
project_dir = os.path.dirname(project_name.__file__)
```

К примеру:

```
>>> import aiohttp
>>> aiohttp.__file__
'/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py'
>>> os.path.dirname(aiohttp.__file__)
'/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp'
>>>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это решение помогло.

Comment: @whyhow можно поставить галочку

Comment: @ eri это мой первый вопрос, можно поподробнее, про галочку? Если это про репу поста, то "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.". Если мой вопрос еще раз лайкнут, то я смогу победить эту несправедливость )))

Comment: @whyhow рядом с репой поста есть галочка, которую ставят на самый подходящий ответ. Сейчас она у Вас серая. Рейтинг уже не так важен после 4000)