# Как записать в папку (которая находится там же где и программа на Python) файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно записать файл в папку, в которой находится сама программа на *Python*.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Месяц назад отвечал..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246045/16574

Answer (score 2):

Создать файл в каталоге расположения исходного кода:

```
file = open("test.txt", "w")
file.close()
```

или создать подкаталог в каталоге расположения исходного кода и создать файл:

```
file = open(r"test\test.txt", "w")
file.close()
```

Comment: Это запись в файл который будет находится в директории самой программы Python Директория_программы\test.txt
А надо  Директория_программы\Название_папки\test.txt

Comment: @Pydeb file = open(r"test\test.txt", "w")

Comment: А почему бы не в одну строчку... `open('test.txt', 'w').close()`

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME я подумал пожелают записать в файл перед закрытием